# Unable to override spring.test.context.cache.maxSize in SpringBoot 2.6.8

Tags: spring, spring-boot

The SpringBoot 2.x is using default value(32) for `spring.test.context.cache.maxSize` all the times. I can't override it in any way.
I tried adding configuration in application-test.yml

```
spring:
     test:
         context:
             cache:
                 maxSize: 64
```

or via CMD
`./gradlew clean test --info -Dspring.test.context.cache.maxSize=64`

The output log:

```
    2022-11-29 11:24:44.681 DEBUG  42856 --- [    Test worker] org.springframework.test.context.cache   : Spring test ApplicationContext cache statistics: [DefaultContextCache@3b713e74 size = 29, maxSize = 32, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 6872, missCount = 54]
```

The max cache context size can be overrided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be a system property. Adding it in the `application.properties` this won't work. The `-D` you are passing is passing it as a JVM parameter to Gradle not the forked JVM for tests.

You need to set it in your `test` task in your `build.gradle` using `systemProperties`.

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
  
  systemProperties['spring.test.context.cache.maxSize'] = 64    
  
}
```

However the fact that you think you need 64 is reason for caution. It is probably a signal that you are overusing/abusing `@SpringBootTest`. Some of which probably are better of as a simple unit test instead of a full blown integration test.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, I tried setting in `gradle.properties`. It's still not working. I found there are 54 test not hitting the cache. So I want to try if it can improve if increasing the cache size.

Comment: Where did I state you need to set `gradle.properties`? You need to configure the task. Also the fact that you have so many permutations of an `ApplicationContext` you might want to avoid, so instead of increasing the cache I would urge you to look at your tests and determine if you really need so many. You are probably abusing `@SpringBootTest` in your tests.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. You are right. It works. Thank you so much.
Another strange thing is that I only have 2500 test cases. But it hit 8709 times which means it loads more than once for some test cases?`[DefaultContextCache@6c71cfc6 size = 31, maxSize = 64, parentContextCount = 0, hitCount = 8709, missCount = 31]`

Comment: If there is an `@DirtiesContext` it will load more. But as stated if you have that many all using a context you are doing testing wrong imho. You are probably abusing `@SpringBootTest` or Spring based tests to do simple unit tests.

Answer (score 0):

Just put it into `spring.properties` file (which can be placed to the root of the Spring library classpath). Then it gets read and used accordingly.